# phpize headers not found lampp

Tags: php, xdebug, lampp, phpize

I'm trying to get xdebug working on a new version of lampp i installed from apachefriends.org. However when executing all the steps from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php i run into troubles with phpize. With my lampp installation i have 3 phpize binaries in `lampp/bin`: `phpize`, `phpize-5.3.8` and `phpize-5.6.20`. However all of them show the following output when invoked

```
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/main/php.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

Obviously there is no include folder in the lampp directory. `phpize` of my command line php version does not work either because of a version mismatch.

Do i need to get some php devel stuff for lampp? Or can i update my cli `php` and `phpize` to an appropriete version?